# Columns left over from table replications: c_Lineage etc

Tags: sql-server

I've inherited a database that I need to cleanup a little. A couple of the tables have these columns called s_GUID, s_ColLineage, s_Generation, and s_Lineage. After a little research I've found that they're inserted when a database is replicated from (old versions of) Access, and that s_GUID is a Globally Unique Identifier that is 16 bits long. Its supposed to be unique across all systems everywhere...how is 16 bits big enough for this?

I've found precious precious little information about what the rest do or why and of them are necessary. Does anybody have any further information regarding the function of these columns? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like those columns are used to track "net" changes.  Meaning, you make a change, you run sync process.  You make more changes, and then run sync process, those columns tell the sync process what final values to replicate, and to whom.  Very similar to what SQL Server's merge replication does.

Bottom line is, if you aren't replicating data anymore, they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

A guide is 128 bits long. It's 16 bytes long.